# How to determine if Entity Changes actually changed anything

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, mvvm

In C#, I'm working with a viewmodel that automatically flips a value back to an original
value if it fails validation (a checkbox). The end result is that no true changes took 
place, however, the Entity records it as a change.

I've investigated many options such as making a copy of the initial state, and then comparing
it to the state of the model when the user causes the program to check for changes. However, using 
that method, it makes a "shallow copy" of the Entity, and so all changes happen to both instances.

I don't want to just make an object where I store all the initial values, because it may be unreliable
in the future, as well as time consuming.

Comment: `because it may be unreliable in the future` What makes you think that would be unreliable in the future?

Comment: There's a lot of information that can be changed from this particular view. I'd feel more comfortable with using a comprehensive object that covers all the different properties as defined by the entity itself, rather than make a loose copy of the object in my viewmodel.